# Как сделать чтобы следующие значение делилось на предыдущие?

Tags: php

Например, есть массив:

```
$array = array("1", "2", "4", "8",  "16")
```

Нужно чтобы следующие значение делилось на предыдущие и выводился результат.
Типа так:

```
2 поделить на 1 и результат  
4 поделить на 2 и результат  
8 поделить на 4 и результат  
16 поделить на 8 и результат
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$array = array("1", "2", "4", "8", "16");

if(count($array) > 1) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if($i > 0) {
            var_dump($array[$i]/$array[$i-1]);
            // либо 
            // var_dump($array[$i]." поделить на ".$array[$i-1]." равно ".$array[$i]/$array[$i-1]);
        }
    }
}
```